# How to install sendy in localhost?

Tags: sendy

I purchased sendy.
When I installed it in local it said "Unlicensed domain".
How to install it in localhost?
I tried a lot, but unsuccessfully.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: If you're still having issues, can I suggest [emailoctopus.com](https://emailoctopus.com)? It's a hosted solution so it's a bit easier to get started with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to talk to the guys at Sendy. Installing and using Sendy requires a license which is attached to / registered with specific domain names. You need to request and let them know you want to use on "localhost".

The alternative is (if you can) to update your development machine's *host* file with the registered domain name such that the domain name (e.g. example.com) points to your local machine *(127.0.0.1)*. That will require you to also set up a site on your web server.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you own a domain you can refer a subdomain to your local computer IP.
Then you install Sendy with this domain.

From Sendy forum: https://sendy.co/forum/discussion/2866/development-licences#Item_2